# HTML CSS Part of Page cut off

Tags: html, css

So I have the HTML and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Solomon Wise</title>
        <style = text/css>
            body {
                background-color: #F5F5DC;
            }
            .body {
                font-family: Futura, Geneva, sans-serif;
                width: 300px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                left: 50px;
                background-color: White;
            }
            .javascript {
                font-family: Futura, Geneva, sans-serif;
                width: 300px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                left: 500px;
                background-color: White;
            }
            .HTMLCSS {
                font-family: Futura, Geneva, sans-serif;
                width: 300px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: White;
                top: 300px;
                left: 500px;
            }
            .Python {
                font-family: Futura, Geneva, sans-serif;
                width: 300px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: White;
                top: 500px;
                left: 500px;
            }
            p {
                color: #747E80;
            }
            a:link {
                color:DarkBlue;
            }
            a:visited {
                color:Black;
            }
            a:hover {
                color:DarkCyan;
                }
        </style>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = 'body'>
        <h1>Solomon Wise</h1>
        <nav>
            <p class = 'one'>Hi, I'm Solomon, I'm 13 years old and I live in NYC. I love music, coding, sports, and minimalism.</p>
            <a href = "http://pastebin.com/u/slmnwise">Pastebin</a></br>
            <a href = "http://turntablestars.com/profile/Bill">TTStars Profile</a>
        </nav>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/slmnwise" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false"><img src = 'http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1161475967.png'></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/SolomonIsGreat.net"><img src = "http://whatnowatlanta.com/wp-content/themes/canvas/images/ico-social-facebook.png"</a>
        <a href="http://www.goodreads.com/user/show/7658526-solomon-wise"><img src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NtFTy_OM9oU/TsaFQylMW-I/AAAAAAAAE2s/XwdLy3eiBbk/s1600/goodreads-button-much-rounder-corners-600x600.jpg" height = "32" width = "32"></a>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1207787/solomon-wise"><img src = "http://alindeman.github.com/images/stackoverflow_32.png"></a></br>
    </div>
    <div class = 'javascript'>
        <h3>Javascript</h3>
        <p class = 'two'>I can make small web applications in Javascript, along with adding dynamic features and functionality to a website in Javascript, such as adding a twitter mashup or an RSS feed.</p>
    </div>
    <div class = 'HTMLCSS'>
        <h3>HTML and CSS</h3>
        <p class = 'three'>I can design snazzy looking websites in HTML and CSS, just contact me to request one and we can work something out!</p>
    </div>
    <div class = 'Python'>
        <h3>Python</h3>
        <p class = 'four'>I can write applications and small games in Python, I have a good bit of experience in the language and work with it a lot</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the website looks perfectly fine, except for one thing. The bottom of the Python box is cut off, and I can't scroll down to view the rest of the page! How do i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` on all those "boxes"...

position fixed means the element doesn't interact with the viewport the same way other ones do so they don't affect the scrolling of the page...

hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 3):

Change the CSS position attribute to

```
position: absolute;
```